# deja-dup restore not prompting for passphrase and subsequently failing

Tags: backup, encryption, gnupg, deja-dup

I'm trying to use Deja-Dup's "Restore Missing" command from within Nautilus to restore some Music files I had accidentally deleted a few months back. Trouble is, I keep getting gpg: bad passphrase errors. The full error is:

```
GPGError: GPG Failed, see log below:
===== Begin GnuPG log =====
gpg: WARNING: "--no-use-agent" is an obsolete option - it has no effect
gpg: AES256 encrypted data
gpg: gcry_kdf_derive failed: Invalid data
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
===== End GnuPG log =====
```

I know the passphrase, but I'm not getting prompted for it. Is there somewhere I can enter it?